# Should we remove the python tag?

Tags: feature-request, tagging, tag-blacklist

Python is not related to math and might have been created accidentally. Currently only three questions are tagged [python](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python).

Comment: The original question creating it will disappear in a couple of weeks, and with it the tag. I've removed it from the other two questions in the meantime.

Comment: Judging by Asaf's comment, it's related to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22816/mse-gains-a-tag-through-migration-tag-lives-on) I recently asked about tags and migrated posts.